# Generalization of Menger's theorem to infinite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics, matching-theory

Aharoni and Berger generalized Menger's Theorem to infinite graphs: For any digraph, and any subsets $A$ and $B$, there is a family $F$ of disjoint paths from $A$ to $B$ and a set separating $B$ from $A$ consisting of one vertex of each path in $F$.

But what I need is a criterion (at least, a useful sufficient condition) telling me when there is a family of disjoint paths from $A$ to $B$ covering all of $A$. (I only need it for acyclic digraphs in which every path has at most $3$ vertices.) What is known?

Answer (score 1):

In [our paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509397), this is called a "linkage". We define something called a "hindrance" and prove that if there is no hindrance then there is a linkage. This is a sufficient but not a necessary condition. In Aharoni's proof of the theorem for bipartite graphs, he defines something called "obstruction", which is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO! I think that for your answer to be useful, you should at least provide a link to the paper.

Comment: I think this is the correct link: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509397